# 3 Screen Setup with 2 MiniDP, 1 HDMI, 1 DVI Port Available?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, displayport

I have a GPU with 2 mini display ports, a dvi port, and an hdmi port.
I have previously tried to set up three screens with this but wasn't able to do so as the displayport screen didn't show anything.

My screens all use HDMI and I use a simple MiniDP to HDMI converter.

This is the exact model of my GPU: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00FV10GF2/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FV10GF2)

What might be wrong here?

The current setup is one screen HDMI to HDMI, one screen DVI to HDMI with adapter, one screen MiniDP to HDMI with adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than two display outputs does not necessarily mean you can have more than two displays.  In the case of this card though - you can.

Do you have a EyefinityDongle for your card? For use of 3 or more displays with AMD Eyefinity technology, you require a DisplayPort-capable panel or an AMD Eyefinity validated dongle. 
Else it will not work.

See [AMD Eyefinity Technology - Recommended Adapters](http://support.amd.com/en-us/recommended/eyefinity-adapters) for a list of validated DisplayPort dongles.

That is one serious card, btw.

Comment: So if I purchase the AMD Eyefinity certified adapter for the MiniDP to HDMI, I should be good to go for the whole setup?

Comment: As per AMD, yes.